# Android TabHost is there a way to get TabView by ID

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabactivity

I'm making some an advanced `TabActivity` but I need to get every `TabView` thats in the `TabHost`. With `tabHost.getCurrentTabView()` I can get the current `TabView` but is there a way to get a `TabView` by its ID?

---

I managed to make a workaround by doing a for loop in the `onCreate()` method where I go to every tab and put all the `View` objects in an Array.

> ```
>   private View[] tabs;
>
>   for(int i = 0; i < getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++)
>     {
>         tabHost.setCurrentTab(i);
>         tabs[i] = tabHost.getCurrentTabView();
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `TabView` in Android.

To find the contents of a tab via its ID, call `findViewById()` on the `TabHost`.