# Button Click on Tab View Android

Tags: android, button, tabs

For some reason that I cannot figure out, when I put the code in for a click of a button inside a tab the application force stops.  Here is the code:

```
Button btn = (Button)tabs.getCurrentView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Here is the logcat

```
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{particularidiom.doodledot/com.yabt.Chooser}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at com.yabt.Chooser.onCreate(Chooser.java:134)
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
02-20 22:31:22.328: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: you need to paste the logcat.

Comment: posting more detail, e.g how many `Activity` do you have in Tabs, this `Button` exits in which `Activity`?? will help us to suggest you the better way..

Comment: Have you declare activity in manifest.If not just check it.

Comment: hello , in my case i have tabview layout with an extra button,
now how can i get click of this button inside tabactivity?

any one have idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find answer in the below link

[Android TabHost is there a way to get TabView by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403387/android-tabhost-is-there-a-way-to-get-tabview-by-id)

Mostly it will help to you

Answer (score 0):

I suppose button, `btn` in your code is null. May be you are not getting exact `R.id` in the above code sample.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand what you mean. I only have one button with that id, and created that in the xml.

Comment: Are you doing setcontentView before the line that you have posted?? pls post that code as well

Comment: I was able to solve the problem.  I needed to specify the tab it was on.